# NavigationLink is only tappable on text section

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationLink:

```swift
NavigationLink("Login") {
    WelcomeView()
}
.foregroundColor(.white)
.frame(width:300, height: 50)
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(10)
.padding()
.disabled(authenticateUser())
```

which looks like this:

[image]

The issue is that the navigation only occurs when the user taps directly on the word "Login". If the user taps anywhere on the blue area outside of the text - no navigation occurs and nothing happens.

How do I modify the NavigationLink so that the user can tap anywhere inside its frame to navigate to the linked in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are styling the background of the `NavigationLink`, but only the text is clickable. Instead, make use of [`NavigationLink.init(destination: (), label: ()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s). Here's an example using what you did, but allowing the entire button to be clickable:

```swift
NavigationLink {
    //Your destination here
    WelcomeView()
} label: {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        Text("Login")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}.frame(width: 300, height: 50)
.padding().disabled(authenticateUser())
```

Also, somewhat off topic but I might have the disabled be based on the result of a `ViewModel` that you call at the start in an `@Published` variable - using `.onAppear` and checking then. That would make it so you could update it if necessary. Here's a video of the behavior now:
[image: A GIF of the new behavior]